# res.cookie stops creating cookies after a long period of time

Tags: node.js, express

I have having an extremely odd and infuriating issue. Res.cookie stops setting cookies for some users after the users have existed for a long period of time. The newer user cookies set fine, even on the same browser.

```
    var token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
          expiresIn: "1 day" // expires in 24 hours
      });
      console.log(token.length)
      res.cookie('token', token, { maxAge: 9000000, httpOnly: false});
```

Is how the token is set.

```
  var token = req.cookies['token'];



if (token) {
   jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {


     .....
     }
```

is how it is read. 
The output of req.cookies is {}.

Has anybody seen this issue before? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The token was becoming too large for the cookie to set.